# Move Box with the mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, math

Im trying to move a box on canvas as the player moves but can't figure out the correct maths to do so im trying to do something simular to the draggable of the jquery function exept on canvas.

Here my code so far:

```
var _proto = {left:0,top:0,left2:0,top2:0};
var _isClicked = false;

$("canvas").on("mousedown", function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    _proto.left = e.pageX-offset.left; //left of screen works fine,mouse
    _proto.top = e.pageY-offset.top; //top of screen works fine,mouse
    _isClicked = true;

    $(this).on("mousemove", function(e) {

        _proto.left2 = (e.pageX-offset.left); //get new pos mouse, works fine
        _proto.top2 = (e.pageY-offset.top); //get new pos mouse, works fine

        //Obj is an array of proto's objects,
        // It moves the box to quick and incorrect
        _objects[0].left = _proto.left2-(_proto.left-_objects[0].left);
        _objects[0].top = _proto.top2-(_proto.top-_objects[0].top);

        if(_isClicked == false) $(this).off("mousemove");        
    });

}).on("mouseup", function(e) {
    _isClicked = false;
});
```

---

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/CezarisLT/tUXM3/**

Comment: One note: Instead of binding and unbinding to mouse move, bind once and have an `if` statement that returns if `_isClicked` is `false`.

Comment: What is the `_moveid` variable? And why are you assigning left and top properties to `_objects[0]` using the current value of `_objects[_moveid]`?

Comment: In general: `element.style.left = element.offsetLeft + e.clientX - mx + 'px'`, where `mx` is a previous value of `e.clientX`. Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cww55/6/). Though the fiddle has been written with vanilla JS, you can get the idea.

Comment: @MattWilson can you please demonstrate this example? I'm not sure whats the difference? Also myid is just zero for this test.

Comment: @Teemu added a demo, very similar code still im missing something

Comment: @CezarisLT I'm sorry, at the moment I can't follow your logic... Even more general: `newPosX = currentPosX + dX`, where `dX` is `[current]e.pageX - [previous]e.pageX`, and the corresponding math for `Y` values.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use event streams to solve problems like these. What is an event stream? It is a stream of events. So let's create our own `EventStream` constructor:

```
function EventStream() {
    var listeners = this.listeners = [];

    return [this, function (event) {
        return listeners.map(function (listener) {
            return listener(event);
        });
    }];
}
```

We won't be using the `EventStream` constructor directly. Instead we'll write a function which creates an event stream, subscribes it to a stream of events and returns the stream:

```
function getEventStream(event, target) {
    var pair = new EventStream;
    target.addEventListener(event, pair[1]);
    return pair[0];
}
```

Now we can create event streams as follows:

```
var move = getEventStream("mousemove", window);
```

Now we have a stream of `mousemove` events stored in the variable `move`. So how do we use it? The beauty of event streams is that you can `map` over, `filter`, `scan` and `merge` them. This makes life much easier.

---

First let's see the `map` method:

```
EventStream.prototype.map = function (f) {
    var pair = new EventStream;
    var dispatch = pair[1];

    this.listeners.push(function (x) {
        return dispatch(f(x));
    });

    return pair[0];
};
```

The `map` method does two things:

1. It allows you to subscribe to an event.
2. It allows you to process an event stream, creating an entirely new event stream.

Now let's look at the `filter` method:

```
EventStream.prototype.filter = function (f) {
    var pair = new EventStream;
    var dispatch = pair[1];

    this.listeners.push(function (x) {
        if (f(x)) return dispatch(x);
    });

    return pair[0];
};
```

The `filter` method, as the name implies, filters the events in an event stream. It returns an entirely new event stream with the filtered events.

Next up, the `scan` method:

```
EventStream.prototype.scan = function (a, f) {
    var pair = new EventStream;
    var dispatch = pair[1];
    dispatch(a);

    this.listeners.push(function (x) {
        return dispatch(a = f(a, x));
    });

    return pair[0];
};
```

The `scan` method allows us to create *"properties"* which change from event to event, creating a new *"property event stream"*. It's a very useful function which I'll demonstrate how to use below.

Finally we have the `merge` method:

```
EventStream.prototype.merge = function (stream) {
    var pair = new EventStream;
    var dispatch = pair[1];

    this.listeners.push(function (x) {
        return dispatch({left: x});
    });

    stream.listeners.push(function (x) {
        return dispatch({right: x});
    });

    return pair[0];
};
```

The `merge` method takes two events streams and merges them into a single event stream. To distinguish which event stream originated which event we tag each event as either `left` or `right`.

---

Now that we learned about event streams let's use them to create a draggable box on a canvas and see how they make life so simple.

The first thing we do is set up the canvas:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

var position = getPosition(canvas);

var left = position.left;
var top = position.top;
```

The `getPosition` function is defined as follows:

```
function getPosition(element) {
    if (element) {
        var position = getPosition(element.offsetParent);

        return {
            left: position.left + element.offsetLeft,
            top:  position.top  + element.offsetTop
        };
    } else {
        return {
            left: 0,
            top:  0
        };
    }
}
```

Next we create a constructor for a `Box`:

```
function Box(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
}

Box.prototype.bind = function (context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    return context;
};
```

Then we create a box and draw it to the screen:

```
var box = new Box(100, 100, 150, 150);
box.bind(context).fill();
```

Now we need to make it draggable. We start dragging by holding down the mouse button. So the first thing we do is create a `mousedown` event stream:

```
var down = getEventStream("mousedown", canvas);
```

We want the coordinates of the `mousedown` events relative to the canvas. In addition we only want those `mousedown` events which occur on top the box. This can easily be handled using event streams as follows:

```
var dragStart = down

.map(function (event) {
    return {
        x: event.clientX - left,
        y: event.clientY - top
    };
})

.filter(function (cursor) {
    return box.bind(context).isPointInPath(cursor.x, cursor.y);
});
```

Now you have a stream of `mousedown` events on top of your box.

Next we get a stream of `mouseup` events because dragging stops once you pick up your finger from the mouse button:

```
var up = getEventStream("mouseup", window);
```

We get `mouseup` events for the entire window because the user should be able to mouse the mouse outside the canvas and release it.

Next we merge the `dragStart` and `up` event streams to create a single `dragStartStop` event stream:

```
var dragStartStop = dragStart.merge(up).map(function (x) {
    return x.left;
});
```

Events from the `up` event stream don't have any useful information. They only serve to mark that the user has stopped dragging. Hence we only care about events from the `left` event stream.

Coming back, to actually drag the box we need `mousemove` events. So let's get a `mousemove` event stream:

```
var move = getEventStream("mousemove", canvas).map(function (event) {
    return {
        x: event.clientX - left,
        y: event.clientY - top
    };
});
```

Like with the `dragStart` stream we only want the coordinates of `mousemove` events relative to the canvas.

Now we can `merge` the `dragStartStop` and the `move` streams to create the final `drag` stream:

```
var drag = dragStartStop.merge(move)

.scan(null, function (prev, event) {
    if (event.hasOwnProperty("left")) {
        var left = event.left;
        return left && [left, left];
    } else if (prev) return [prev[1], event.right];
})

.filter(function (x) {
    return x;
})

.map(function (position) {
    var prev = position[0];
    var current = position[1];

    return {
        dx: current.x - prev.x,
        dy: current.y - prev.y
    };
});
```

Here we `scan` the events of the merged streams to create a *"property event stream"* of previous and current mouse positions when the user is dragging the box. We `filter` those `mousemove` events when the user is dragging the box and we get the difference in positions between the previous and current `mousemove` events.

Now we can draw the box being dragged:

```
drag.map(function (position) {
    box.x += position.dx;
    box.y += position.dy;

    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    box.bind(context).fill();
});
```

That's it. Simple right? See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PC3m8/

---

So what do we conclude from this? Event streams are awesome and you should use streams instead of creating big monolithic event listeners. They make your code more readable, understandable and maintainable and they make everybody's life simpler.

Comment: This is a great answer but can you explain how isPointInPath is used for multiple objects?

Comment: @CezarisLT The `isPointInPath` method belongs to the canvas API. See the following canvas cheat sheet: http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas_sheet/HTML5_Canvas_Cheat_Sheet.png The `isPointInPath` method is used to determine whether the given `x` and `y` coordinates are bounded by the currently active path: http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/february/an-example-of-the-html5-canvas-ispointinpath-function.html Once you begin a path you may either `fill` it, `stroke` it, `clip` it or use `isPointInPath`. In my answer I `bind` a shape (i.e. begin a path). Then I just use `isPointInPath` or anything else